# Exibir Popup ao perceber que o usuário irá sair da página

Tags: javascript, html

Estou querendo exibir um PopUp para exibir um formulário para captar o e-mail e o nome do usuário que está acessando o site no momento que ele estiver perto de sair do site. Vejo isso comumente em diversas landings pages, principalmente nas focadas em conversão de leads. Sempre que arrasto a seta do mouse para o botão fechar do navegador, aparece o PopUp.

Comment: Acho que neste link diz alguma coisa: <a href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40982/exibir-algo-ao-tentar-fechar-meu-site"> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40982/exibir-algo-ao-tentar-fechar-meu-site</a>

Comment: Você poderá gostar desse https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/229319/evento-ao-tirar-o-mouse-da-janela/229356#229356

Answer (score 2):

Neste caso, o que você quer é o evento de quando o usuário tira o mouse da janela. Para isso pode usar uma solução assim:

Criar uma função que aplica evento de modo cross-browser:

```
function addEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
    }
    else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
    }
}
```

E então aplicar o evento para quando ocorrer a saída do mouse na janela::

```
addEvent(document, "mouseout", function(e) {
    e = e ? e : window.event;
    var from = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;
    if (!from || from.nodeName == "HTML") {
        // Aqui você coloca o seu popup
        alert("left window");
    }
});
```

Segue abaixo o código completo de exemplo:

```js
function addEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
    }
    else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
    }
}
addEvent(window,"load",function(e) {
    addEvent(document, "mouseout", function(e) {
        e = e ? e : window.event;
        var from = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;
        if (!from || from.nodeName == "HTML") {
            // Aqui você coloca o seu popup
            alert("left window");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Show de bola! Fiz em um projeto que está em angular na versão 12 e funcionou perfeitamente!